# Why do I now get a "Suggested Edits" link and what am I expected to do?

Tags: support

For the first time, I received a link from SO when someone edited my question. It takes me to the "Suggested Edits" page. I may be wrong, but I think I had questions edited in the past but never got this. Why am I getting it now?

And what is the purpose of me receiving this? I don't see any option for me to OK or not OK the edits or any other option for that matter. Is this being sent just for informational purposes?

Comment: You got a notification in the site inbox, you mean? Could you include the link to the review in this post?

Comment: It's likely the edit was approved by reviewers before you clicked on the link - so the review was already actioned. Usually, though, you get the deciding vote on whether or not to accept the change.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I received the notification in my email. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11664913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO will now notify you when someone edits your questions and answers, but only when it was a substantial edit. It's just a courtesy notice is all so you can review the changes. If you don't like the changes you can always do a rollback or make new changes.

> In order to reduce noise sent to users, we only notify when "substantive" changes are happening on their posts.

[No notification was received for an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202359/no-notification-was-received-for-an-edit-to-a-post/202415#202415)

Comment: I must be missing something obvious. I can not find any place to do a "rollback". Is this option on the Suggested Edits page or on the original question page?

Comment: There will be a link under your post that says `edited X mins ago` (or something similar depending how long ago the edit was). In that screen you will see the history of your post. The rollback option will be on previous versions

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.